# Is the data stored using NSUserDefaults deleted when the app is updated?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsuserdefaults

Currently I'm creating an app that is storing data using NSUserDefaults.

So when I upload v1 of the app to the app store and then make a new update for the app (v2) **is the data stored in NSUsedDefaults deleted when the user updates to the new version?**

Comment: Why would the data be deleted? Think about the millions of annoyed people there would be if data was deleted simply for updating an app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The data stored with `NSUserDefaults` is not deleted when the user updates the app.

It will only be deleted if the user deletes the app.

Comment: Is the data lost in nsuserdefaluts when we double click the home button and remove the object.

Comment: No, the data is not deleted when the user forces your app to close. However, the latest changes might be lost if they are not synced yet.